# How to use Non-assignment expressions in Flex as3 using Flex SDK?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I was looking in to [ActionScript 3 Specification](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=000_titlepage.html) in that i noticed **Non-assignment expressions** under index -> 14 Expressions > 14.18 Non-assignment expressions. Is it possible to assign data type for a variable dynamically through ternary operator ?: like below as mentioned in docx..

A NonAssignmentExpression may be used where ever a TypeExpression may be used.

```
var x : hintString ? String : Number
```

If its is possible in as3 when i build this using flex SDK i got Syntax Error

```
> src\App.mxml(29):  Error: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before String.
                   var x1: h1 ? String : Number;
```

for the below code.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            creationComplete="onComplete()">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        private function onComplete():void
        {
            //test 
            var h1:String = 'hai';
            var x1: h1 ? String : Number;
            Alert.show("Type of x1 :"+typeof(x1));

        }

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

</s:Application>
```

If it is possible in as3 and why not in Flex ? I have checked in Adobe docs on [conditional operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional) but nothing is mentioned there like the above why?

Comment: Interesting question. What you've written there is ActionScript 3.0 so it's not possible regardless of whether you're writing pure ActionScript 3.0 or ActionScript 3.0 within a Flex context. I've worked with the language since it was born and I've never seen that construct before. Not sure why it would appear in the specification, though I don't have a huge amount of faith in the accuracy of Adobe's documentation.

Comment: Are you sure that h1 can be a string? I think it must be a boolean variable.

Comment: Whatever the datatype of h1 the error is same. It seems that the Adobe AS3 specification doc is wrong or i have not understood the concept behind the spec. I tried changing that to Boolean also.

Comment: Tamarin bug report. "Conditional type syntax documented but not implemented nor implementable" - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568452 -

Comment: If that was not implement then why they have to mention that in the specification document?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. What you've written there is ActionScript 3.0 so the construct isn't possible regardless of whether you're writing pure ActionScript 3.0 or ActionScript 3.0 within a Flex context. I've worked with the language since it was born and I've never seen that construct before.

My best guess is that it must be an error in the AS 3.0 specification document. There's nothing about it in the proposed [Proposed ECMAScript 4th Edition – Language Overview document](http://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Languages/Language%20overview.pdf) and this [Mozilla Tamarin bug report page](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568452) says it's (quote) "not implemented nor implementable".

As a side-note, I'm struggling to think of an application for this construct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, really interesting question, thanks for pointing it.
I tried:

```
var h1:String = null; //(if try var h1:String = 'hai' the output will be [class String]
var x1 = h1 ? String : Number;
// probably the same result as x1:*

trace(x1); // [class Number]
```

I just checked the abc of this test and when we use this approach or *, it uses **coerce_a** (Indicates to the verifier that the value on the stack is of the any type ( * ). Does nothing to value.)

I agree with @net.uk.sweet, about struggling to think of an application for this construct..

Comment: Are you really think it's dinamic assignment of type? As far as I can see it's just assignment link to the class. It's the same as: var h1:String = null; //(if try var h1:String = 'hai' the output will be [class String]
var x1:Class = h1 ? String : Number; but without type cheking

Comment: Nope, I do not, pay attention to my answer and you will see my reference, telling the result is the same as var x1:*

Comment: I think it's just tells difference in produced bytecode by compiler in cases var x1 = "something" and var x1:* = "something"

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to be more clear next time :)
Just making things clear, I do not think it's dynamic assignment